# spectrum of compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Let $\phi\in\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$. For $p\in[1,\infty]$, define

$$M_\phi:\ell^p\to\ell^p,\quad f\mapsto\phi f.$$

Use spectral theory to show that, if $M_\phi$ is compact, then $\phi\in c_0$. Here all sequence spaces are over the field $\mathbb{C}$.

I have no idea how to apply spectral theory, I know how to prove the claim without using them.

Comment: You don't need anything: if $|\phi(k)|\ge\delta>0$ on an infinite set $k\in I$, observe that $\{e_k: k\in I\}$ is not mapped to a relatively compact set.

Comment: @ChristianRemling That is right. But the question requires to use spectral theory.

Answer (score 0):

If $M_\phi$ is compact, its spectrum is countable and has only zero as a limit point. Since  $e_k$ are eigenvectors for $M_\phi$, with eigenvalues $\phi(k)$, it follows that $\phi(k) \to 0$.

Comment: I think this works for pairwise distinct eigenvalues. Then we have to first claim that the spectrum is countably infinite.

Comment: it does not depend on pairwise distinct eigenvalues. Any eigenvalue will have only finite multiplicity (the dimension of its eigenspace is finite. ) Hence, any limit point of the sequence $\phi(k)$ will be a limit point of the spectrum of $M_\phi$.